# How to make callback function execute limited times?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have tried to complete the function `limitedFunction`, but really have no idea how to limit the execution times for the callback function.

```
//complete the function limitedFunction(maxExecTime, cb), which not run the cb function if it's called over the maxExecTime
let fn = limitedFunction(3, (a,b,c)=>a+b+c)
fn([1,2,3]) // 6
fn([1,2,3]) // 6
fn([1,2,3]) // 6
fn([1,2,3]) // over limit
fn([1,2,3]) // over limit
```

Answer (score 2):

You just keep track of how many time the wrapped function has been called.

```js
function limitedFunction(maxExecTime, fn) {
  let execTime = 0

  return (...args) => {
    if (execTime >= maxExecTime) {
      throw new Error('Over the limit')
    }

    // as we are about to call the wrapped function, let's increment our counter
    execTime++

    // then we call the original function
    return fn(...args)
  }
}

const fn = (a, b) => console.log(`${a} ${b}`);
const limited = limitedFunction(3, fn);

limited('call', '1'); // works
limited('call', '2'); // works
limited('call', '3'); // works
limited('call', '4 should fail'); // error
```